# Possible to theme the form's elements with own twig?

Tags: theming, forms, hooks

I was thinking to get twig outputs so I could use these twig variables on a `form.html.twig` such as below:

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ form.name }}
            {{ form.mail }}
            {{ form.subject }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ form.body }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ form.submit }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea how to get the similar variables via hooks on `MYTHEME.theme`?

Answer (score 1):

I found out a solution which I ended with using `{{ element.[machine name] }}` instead of `{{ children }}` on my custom template which is cloned by `form.html.twig`. The result of the code look similar below:

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ element.name }}
            {{ element.mail }}
            {{ element.subject }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ element.body }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ element.submit }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you have other suggestion, I am happy to know! :)

Comment: Use form--[form-id].html.twig otherwise this template file will apply to every single form which you may not want.

Comment: Yes, I have own template. Maybe I was not formulated clearly, I have own such as `form--[form-id].html.twig` which I cloned the template from `form.html.twig` ;)

Comment: This is not always the best approach, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/249856/custom-registration-twig-template

Comment: Do you have a better solution? I would like to theme with twig too, any idea?

Comment: Yes, see this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/245427/47547

Comment: But it is based on form, will it work with element too? I tried this, but no luck - maybe need some changes?

Comment: The most important change is the template name. You can't use `form--[form-id].html.twig`, because this is the form wrapper normally rendering only the `<form>` tag.